# Canon XF100 live stream -- additional hardware needed

Tags: hardware, streaming, hdmi, laptop

Question: How to get the XF100 to live-feed into a laptop for streaming?

Details:
I currently have a Canon XF100 HD video camera, and I need to use it for live streaming of some upcoming events.  I also need to do a HD stream (opposed to SD).  The outputs on the camera are HDMI, YPbPr, and SD RCA plugs.

I would think HDMI or YPbPr with red/white audio would be best, however the part I need to know is, how do I get this into a laptop?  A desktop is not an option in this case.   We do have some laptops around, but we also might be able to get a new laptop if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a capture card.  If you have either USB3 or Thunderbolt, then you can use something like the [Black Magic Intensity](http://www.blackmagicdesign.com/products/intensity) or [Matrox MXO2](http://www.matrox.com/video/en/products/mxo2_mini/streaming/).  You could also consider a stand alone device that is capable of handling the streaming for you directly, such as the [Matrox Monarch](http://www.matrox.com/video/en/products/monarch_hd/) or similar devices that don't have to rely on the computer's processing to send the stream.

Comment: going the black magic intensity route.

Comment: For getting this to work with the blackmagic intensity, and OBS for streaming, I had to go into control panel and then into the blackmagic control panel, set it to hdmi, and use 1080i 59.97. After that was set, I opened OBS and for my source I set it to decklink, and then clicked the config for that, and set it to 1080i 59.97. then finally on the page where I selected decklink, I turned on custom resolution and set it to 1920x1080 with a 29.97 frame rate.

It's extremely touchy on the settings, everything has to match everywhere, also downgraded drivers from 9.8 to 9.7